# Need to get a variable value from a view into my controller

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-2

I am very new to codeigniter and even though I have researched about how to get a variable from the view and pass it to my controller. I still not able to do it.

I have a form_input embedded in bootstrap and I use JavaScript to validate the field in my view but I need to get/pass that form_input value to my controller. How should I do that or what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help!

this code is from my controller:

```
else if($this->spw_user_model->isUserProfessor(getCurrentUserId($this)) && $input){

        var_dump($this->input->get('email_address'));

        $inputForm = json_decode($input);
        $success = $this->spw_vm_request_model->updateRequestsFromProject($inputForm);
        echo json_encode(array("success"=>$success));

    }
```

this code is from my view:

```
</div>
<label for="usr">email address:</label>
<?php
    echo form_input(array(
                        'id' => 'email_address',
                        'name' => 'email_address',
                        'type' => 'email',
                        'placeholder' => 'email@example.com',
                        'value' => set_value('email_address'),
                        'required' => '',
                        'title' => 'Email address'
                        ));
?>

<!--<input  type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control"/>-->
<button id="submitRequests" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
</div>
```

basically, I load the view and when a button written in javascript is clicked the page should submit it functionality and the input filed should pass it values to the controller. I might have not explained everything 100 % but that is the idea> I don't know f the input field will be just working with a form_button but anyways I don't think that should be the case

Comment: I really didn't understand what you are trying to say over here ...can you clarify the question ? If you are looking for ways to submit the value to the controller try using Jquery GET or Ajax GET method. I am not sure what exactly you are looking for

Comment: well, i want to get the value from the form_input  into my controller using something like :

$this->input->get('email_addres');
but t is not working properly for me, neither 
$this->input->post('email_addres');

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#submitRequests").click(function(){
    $.get("YOUR_CONTROLLER_URL",{email_address:$('#email_address').val()},function(data){
    });
});
```

Give the controller URL in above statement & make sure you have incuded Jquery

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have code like that already doing that but I want to use codeigniter in this case. How can i do it with codeigniter

Comment: well, when you use a button instead of Submit , you can use only javascript. Put a form with get method & then use a submit button instead of the button you are using.  Button will not do anything, unless you link it with JS

Comment: Okay, thanks. 
so, I need to add a form_button to be able to get the form_input value correct? the javascript button does not support that functionality, unless I link/embed the javascript button with the form_button correct? or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work `$this->input->post('email_address', TRUE);`

There is a spelling mistake in your `$this->input->post('email_addres');`, note the `email_addres` another `s` is missing.